# Eclipse @deprecated not working, but @Deprecated work

Tags: java, eclipse

In my Eclipse Indigo, only `@Deprecated` work but not `@deprecated` in comment, any idea?

e.g.

```
// @deprecated <-- not work
@Deprecated    <-- work
public String getName()
{
    return name;
}
```

Comment: That comment is not a javadoc comment, so it means nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comment is not a javadoc comment so it is ignored by Eclipse. If you would have used

```
/**
 * @deprecated
 */
```

then Eclipse would have handled it exactly the same as when you specify the `@Deprecated` annotation.

Answer (score 7):

@Deprecated is a marker interface whereas deprecated is not. [@deprecated](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javadoc/deprecation/deprecation.html#javadoc_tag) is a Javadoc Tag.

Answer (score 3):

I believe `@deprecated` is only for use in Javadoc comments in explaining deprecation, and is not itself an annotation usable on methods.

Comment: And since annotations are interfaces they are case-sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

**1.** Annotation types are, in fact, a **form of interface**.

**2.** the `@Deprecated` annotation **indicates that the marked element is deprecated and should no longer be used.**

**3.** When an element is deprecated, it should also be **documented** using the Javadoc `@deprecated` tag, which means that `@deprecated` **is only for the use in Javadoc documentation, and not for applying on the methods**.

For more details see this:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/annotations.html